# Trigger Insert multiple data from multiple table MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

i wanna ask something.
i want to add new data using trigger. the value data from multiple database table, and i want use "|" as separator. for example "VALUE1 | VALUE2", and the result must be christin | new york

example of my trigger code:

```
begin
 DECLARE value1 VARCHAR(50);
 DECLARE value2 VARCHAR(50);

 SELECT some_item INTO value1 FROM table1 WHERE id=NEW.id;
 SELECT some_item2 INTO value2 FROM table2 WHERE id=NEW.id;
   INSERT INTO my_table(id,new_value)values( NEW.id, value1 | value2);

end
```

how should i write my code? i dont have any error but the result from value1 and value2 is wrong. the result is just "value1 | value2" not "christin | new york".

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already know the answer. i just using concat in my insert query.
my query now :

```
begin
  DECLARE value1 VARCHAR(50);
  DECLARE value2 VARCHAR(50);

  SELECT some_item INTO value1 FROM table1 WHERE id=NEW.id;
  SELECT some_item2 INTO value2 FROM table2 WHERE id=NEW.id;
  INSERT INTO my_table(id,new_value)values( NEW.id, concat(value1," | ",value2));

  end
```

Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to assign values to your variables via `SELECT` command. If it is, so try to do this:

```
SELECT some_item INTO @value1 FROM table1 WHERE id=NEW.id;
SELECT some_item2 INTO @value2 FROM table2 WHERE id=NEW.id;
```

<s>Assuming that `@value1` and `@value2` are the variables defined in the top of your script.</s>

Answer (score 0):

I find that you wanted to concatenate two strings, isn't it?

```
-- you should use function CONCAT_WS
INSERT INTO my_table(id,new_value)values( NEW.id, CONCAT_WS('|', value1, value2) );
```

And you probably applied [bit operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html) by mistatke.

Comment: I would use CONCAT_WS instead of CONCAT - as in case the value1 or value2 will be NULL - the result of function CONCAT also returns NULL. SELECT CONCAT('xmass', '|', NULL) FROM dual; -> NULL